# Accessing member of a class. This class's object was never instantiated. All members are of type static

Tags: c++, static

I have a working codebase that has a class called Tabs. All methods and variables of this class are defined as static. I understand that a static member of class is shared by all instances of that class's objects. This class is used to store some type of data into as sets. A lot of different files use the member functions Tabs::find() and Tabs::Insert() without ever instantiating an object of class Tabs. I'm trying to understand how this works and what this programming technique is called. Thanks.

Comment: It's called using global variables (wrapped in a static-only class).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`static` data members are initialized before `main` enters, that's why accessing them works. They reside in static memory, as opposed to dynamic or automatic.

A class with only static members is similar to having global variables and functions, but grouped together. It's not a programming technique in itself. It's just globals.

```
//globals.h
class Globals
{
   static int x;
public:
   static int getX() {return x;}
};

//globals.cpp
#include "Globals.h"
int Globals::x = 1;

//main.cpp
#include "Globals.h"
//x is initialized before call to main
int main()
{
    int x = Globals::getX();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What I'd call this would be "obsolete". It's essentially using a `class` (or `struct`, as the case may be) to emulate a `namespace`.

```
class whatever { 
    static int a, b, c;
    static double x, y, z;
};

int whatever::a, whatever::b, whatever::c;
double whatever::x, whatever::y, whatever::z;
```

Is pretty much the same as:

```
namespace whatever {
    int a, b, c;
    double x, y, z;
}
```

You're probably just dealing with code that predates `namespace` having been added to the language. If it's not quite that old, the author may be, or perhaps there was some intent to maintain portability to some compiler that didn't support `namespace` (properly).

In any case, what you have are global variables with qualified names. Even though they're inside a `class`/`struct`, the `static` means they have static lifetime, so being a struct affects only the name, not things like initialization or destruction.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to declare the variables `extern`?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: just like with any other global, you'd define them without `extern` one place, and if you want to use them from other TUs, you'd declare them `extern` in those (normally by putting the declaration in a header and including it where needed).